Android Studio does not show Flutter in New Flutter Project
I have flutter working and installed Flutter (Google) plugin Android Studio.
$ flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.19.5, on Mageia 9 6.6.22-desktop-1.mga9, locale en_AU.UTF-8)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Linux toolchain - develop for Linux desktop
[✓] Android Studio (version 2023.2)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)
[✓] Network resources
• No issues found!

$ flutter devices
Found 2 connected devices:
  Linux (desktop) • linux  • linux-x64      • Mageia 9 6.6.22-desktop-1.mga9
  Chrome (web)    • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 123.0.6312.86

When I click on New Flutter Project. Set up the correct PATH to Dart and Flutter. Unfortunately, Android Studio does not show Flutter/Dart.



What did I miss?

'Unfortunately, Android Studio does not show Flutter/Dart' - where exactly do you expected to see Flutter/Dart ??
you should set SDK, set project name, location, type, platform etc. in other words you should just press Create button in last screen(shot).

What's wrong? Just press create and your Flutter project will be created

Thank you, it works. I assume Kotlin and swift are there for native code.
